# fish shell completions keep-order

Tags: fish, tab-completion

How do I use `--keep-order` ?

My function looks like this:

```
function filterfile -a file -a word
    grep -i $word $file
    grep -iv $word $file | sponge $file
end
```

and my completions look like this:

```
complete -k -c filterfile --require-parameter --no-files -a "(cat (commandline -opc)[2])"
complete -k -c filterfile --require-parameter
```

Following the documentation "[Multiple complete calls with -k result in arguments of the later ones displayed first](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/complete.html)", but when I press tab for a file path nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a function `filterfile` which takes two arguments, a filename and a word to search for in the file. You would like the first argument to tab-complete as file names, and the second argument to tab-complete as words given in the file from the first argument.

You can do this by using the `--condition` option (short `-n`) to `complete`, [documented here](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/complete.html). Here we use the helper function `__fish_is_first_arg` to control when our completions run:

```
# Complete first argument as files.
complete -c filterfile --condition __fish_is_first_arg --force-files

# Complete remaining arguments as words in the file from the first argument.
complete --keep-order -c filterfile --condition 'not __fish_is_first_arg' --no-files -a '(cat (__fish_first_token))'
```

Now the first argument should tab-complete as files, and the second+ arguments should tab-complete as words found in the file named by the first argument.

(Note that `__fish_is_first_arg` is [an ordinary fish function](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/57bcbfa8630de051d6a973f04b270aa0beccf69d/share/functions/__fish_is_first_arg.fish#L2) that ships with fish.)

To answer your original question, the `--keep-order` option offers completions in the order they are printed, instead of sorting. With `--keep-order`:

```bash
> cat words.txt
sweater
handy
scarecrow
card
geese

> filterfile words.txt <tab>
sweater  handy  scarecrow  card  geese
```

The completions appear in their original order. Without:

```
> filterfile words.txt <tab>
card  geese  handy  scarecrow  sweater
```

the completions are sorted alphabetically.